# How to patch delta lines to a file using HTTP Patch in JAVA?

Tags: java, rest, file, http-patch

I did try to search on how how to update delta part of file, but information I got is more focused on PATCH topic instead of file update itself.

I am afraid I am missing something obvious.

Can anyone help me with code or to a blog where it is shown?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Are you writing a client which will send PATCH requests? Are you writing a server which will receive them?

Comment: @tgdavies, I am actually writing both. Until now, I used to send whole content of file from client and on server side, I will overwrite the whole file content. I wanted to think of a better way, in case file become huge.

Comment: So what do you need help with?

Comment: Just using the PATCH verb doesn't do anything except document that you are doing a partial update. You need to choose the format your data will be in, e.g. a diff, or a list of line numbers and the new contents for each line, or ...

Comment: I wanted both. Ok. But it looks like the amount of computation it requires to find the differences is more than just updating the file. Thanks for info.